# oracle - How can I increase number automatically, but If the index is different, from zero again

Tags: oracle, jsp

The number goes up automatically, but if the index is different, is there a way to initialize and count it from zero again?

I made member report table

`CREATE TABLE reportTB( idx NUMBER NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINT fk_report_idx foreign key(idx) references memberTB (idx)  ON DELETE CASCADE, reportedNickname varchar2(10 char) NOT NULL, reporterNickname varchar2(10 char) NOT NULL, reason varchar2(200) NOT NULL, reportDate DATE DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, countReport NUMBER NOT NULL );`

so I made 'countrReport' record

and insert into reportTB

`INSERT INTO reportTB ( idx, reportedNickname, reporterNickname, reason, reportDate,countReport)  VALUES ( 2,'james','Iris', 'He used bad words',sysdate,(SELECT NVL(MAX(countReport)+1, 0)FROM reportTB))`

Of course, the next order will be given a value of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I tried it in a sequence, and it was the same Sobbing

I'd like to receive the total number of reported nicknames.

The number goes up automatically every time you insert, but if the index is different, is there a way to initialize and count it from zero again?

Or it would be nice to count the total number of indexes and put them in the countReport value at the same time, but I don't know how to do it at all.

It's Oracle!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgrEK.png)

Comment: I thought it was related because it was an Oracle using Java. I modified it!

Comment: You will need to GROUP BY idx :
(SELECT idx, NVL(MAX(countReport)+1, 0) FROM reportTB GROUP BY idx WHERE idx = 2)

Comment: .... but it's really not the correct way to do it...
either you just need a counter to display as result of queries and you can do it with a row_number() over() in the SELECT clauses, either you really need kind of legacy counting (like an invoice number going back to 1 each fiscal year) and without holes, then you need another mechanism based on a 2 steps commit (1 to validate the business rules, 1 to assign the yet empty legacy number), between the 2: lot of "do it at your taste".

Comment: thanks! I soved it!!! INSERT INTO reportTB(

idx, reportedNickname , reporterNickname , reason , reportDate , countReport )

VALUES (72,'ㄹ','s','아니',sysdate , ( SELECT NVL(COUNT(idx)+1, 0) cnt

FROM reportTB WHERE idx = 72 ))